# find last index of a string in swift

Tags: swift, swift4

In swift 4 you can use the following method to extract a substring:

```
let str = "abcdefghci"
let index = str.index(of: "c") ?? str.endIndex
print(str[...index])
```

This will print `abc`

But how can I find the index of the last `c`, to extract a substring from that location ?

**UPDATE**
@vadian please see the attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `range(of` which can search backwards and use `lowerBound` as end index.

```
let str = "abcdefghci"
if let range = str.range(of: "c", options: .backwards)  {
    print(str[...range.lowerBound])
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`Value of type 'String' has no member 'range'`

Comment: The code snippet must not throw an error.

Comment: please see my update to the post, and I've attached an image to show what error I am getting

Comment: You need to `import Foundation` in the Playground

Comment: thanks-it solved it

Comment: I get Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent error

Comment: @chitgoks My answer doesn't contain any `Int` index, but it seems that you try to subscript an array with an `Int` index. This is not possible.